# How to check in database if a value exist, then display all values with the same ID?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

(I edited my first question to minimize the number of requests)

I'm working on a wordpress website, using Avada Theme Fusion template. I created a form using their form builder. Entries are saved in my database in a table: `wp_fusion_form_entries`.

There is a `submission_id` column that store an ID everytime someone submit the form. There is also a `field_id` column that store the ID of each field. And a `value` column where the value of each field is stored.

[Image of the table `wp_fusion_form_entries`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/277mK.jpg)

What I'm trying to do:

If there is a `value` containing the desired email (in my case: `test@gmail.com)`, display other values (but not all) with the same `submission_id`

In my exemple: I find in the 4th form submitted (`submission_id = 4`) the email desired: `test@gmail.com`. Now I want to display other values with the same `submission_id = 4`. Let's say, I wanna display the values corresponding to `field_id 25,26,27`, so: `aucun`, `bcaa, whey` & `aucun`

I tried a lot of things but I'm lost. I wrote the next code, it displays the desired values. But I didn't succeed to filter the results using the `value` containing the email. (Every user submit his own form, containing his own email. So I have to filter the query for a desired email, or every user will get all values from all users)

```
<?php
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( 
    $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT value 
    FROM  wp_fusion_form_entries
    WHERE field_id IN (25,26,27) 
    ")
);
foreach( $result as $results ) {
        echo $results->value;
        echo '</br>';
    }
?>
```

Thanks to anyone, even those who can't help me. And I wish this will help a lot of other people!

Comment: there's quite a bit to this question, and it isn't really clear what you are asking. I suggest that you take a minute, read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which talks about how to ask a good question, then look at your issue and come up with a smaller question to ask. Try to streamline your question down to just 1 issue first,  then when you get that taken care of move on to the next issue.

Comment: The `WHERE x IN (...)` approach is pretty typical. What's the problem here? You're going to have to be more specific about relations, as that might involve `JOIN` operations.

Comment: Gharbad The Weak: Thanks for the reply. I know there are a lot of informations and I’m sorry for this. I thought this would be better to sum all the problematics in a “general post”. Thanks for the advice! If I have no answer until tomorrow I’ll try to post multiples questions and try to add up the answers to build my thing

Comment: Tasman: Thanks for the reply. My problem is that I don’t succeed to build my query. What I made works, but this is a part of what I want. Here I get all values that I’m interested for. But I need to display values only for concerned users. Each user should see different values. When the user submit the form, there are multiple values stored + a value containing the email. Now I want a way to check the values to find the email of the user, and display other values attached in the same form.

Comment: That's not really clear enough when you say "should see different values". At random? From a table associated by user? This is why it helps to have a minimal example here with some sample tables we can use.

Comment: No need (ever) to apoligize for bad English. Anywhere on the internet should expect non-native English speakers. Also your English isn't bad and is fully understandable. You just need to focus your ideas more before writing a question :-)

Comment: Tadman: You are right, I tried to draw a table but didn’t succeed, I better had to send a picture. When I go back home I’ll do it. This would be way better.

Comment: Danblack: Thanks for your kind message :). This is the problem, I spent like 1h30 to write (write, rewrite, rerewrite, rererewrite...) this post. I thought this was finally clear enough but it appears it’s not and I’m sorry for this. When I’m back home I’ll add pictures for more understanding :)